# Dual space of the function $f$ in Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^1{(\mathbb{R})}$. Why the Fourier Transform $\hat{f}\in  L^{\infty}{(\mathbb{R})}$.

Is it because $(L^1{(\mathbb{R})})^*=L^{\infty}{(\mathbb{R})}$?

Comment: I am ready that $(L^1{(\mathbb{R})})^*=L^{\infty}{(\mathbb{R})}$ only if If the measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is sigma-finite is this true?

Comment: This is true for every $\sigma$-finite measure, but as I pointed out in my answer, this is absolutely not related to your question.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the dual of $L^1$.

This is just an immediate consequence of the definition : for every $\xi$, $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int e^{-it \xi} f(t) \, dt$, and so $\left| \hat{f}(\xi) \right| \le \int \left|f(t) \right|dt$ which is a finite constant by definition of $L^1$.

Comment: and ... $\hat{f}(\xi) \in L^1$?

Comment: @Juan Does $\hat{f} \in L^1$ when $f$ is the characteristic function of $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: sorry the in the first comment the question is $\hat{f} \in L^1$?

Comment: And so my comment gives a counterexample showing that $\hat{f}$ doesn't belong necessarily to $L^1$ if $f \in L^1$.

Comment: $\int|\hat{f}(\xi)| d\xi = \int|\int e^{-it \xi} f(t) \, dt|d\xi \leq \int\int | f(t) |\, dtd\xi$, This $\int\int | f(t) |\, dtd\xi$ expression is infinite?

Comment: What mean characteristic function of [-1,1]?